# Linking to a pdf file with html

Tags: html, css, pdf, anchor, local

`<a href="Resources/path.pdf">LINK </a>`

Here is my link I'm keeping my pdf file (path.pdf) in the resources folder and am trying to click this link to open the pdf. When I click it while running local the error is
" Your file was not found
It may have been moved or deleted."

It's clearly there. ive checked, spell checked, and tried changing the location of the pdf file. HTML pages link just fine.

Thanks

Comment: < a href = "Resources/path.pdf" > ok</a>

Comment: make sure you do full path root/ http/root

Comment: You may need to make sure that your server is allowing serving up files of type PDF.  If not, your request will be ignored.

Comment: By running local, are you saying you are opening the HTML file straight up in the browser or via Localhost?

Comment: html to straight up browser

Answer (score 11):

Since you have not clarified for us whether you are using a local host or just viewing the text file in the browser I will assume the latter.

In this case, you would have your anchor tag and in the href attribute put the location of the file

```html
<a href="C:\Users\Shannon Myers\Documents\Biology-DNA\teen_time_report.pdf">ok</a>
```

In the above example I started from my C: drive and went from there. Also you could do it as follows:

```html
<a href="Resources\teen_time_report.pdf">ok</a>
```

This should link to the pdf file that you have in mind, as long as the resources folder and html file are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use local host you can use

```
<a href="./pdfFile.pdf" target="blank">PdfFile</a>
```

it will open new tab in you brower and starts to download the file.

If you hosting like netlify

```
<a href="./pdfFile.pdf" target="blank">PdfFile</a>
```

It will open a new tab showing your pdf file.

Comment: These lines are both the same and this question is 4 years old.

Answer (score -2):

Though not necessary for user interaction, you may consider adding these attributes to your "a" tag, to tell search engines what the link is for:

- "type" = "application/pdf"
- "rel" = "alternate" (if the linked pdf contains the same content as the linking page)
- "media" = "print" (if the linked PDF is primarily used for printing)

Example:

```
<a href="./pdfFile.pdf" target="_blank" type="application/pdf" rel="alternate" media="print">...</a>
```

Learn more about "a" tag attributes on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: Nothing here addresses the problem the question is asking about.

Comment: There is no `media` attribute for `a` elements. W3Schools is (a) generally awful and (b) wrong in this specific case.